# Should you say "Bircat HaGomel" after receiving outpatient test results?

Tags: halacha, hagomel

I know that someone who has recovered from a serious illness or returned from a long hospital stay recites *Bircat Hagomel*.

Should you or would it be appropriate to recite the bracha after receiving positive results from certain outpatient tests or minor procedures such as the following:

- colonoscopy / endoscopy
- throat culture confirms that you do not have strep throat
- MRI / Cat Scan confirms that a suspected part of your body which might have required major surgery does not need surgery and can be treated via medications or physical therapy, diet, etc.
- biopsy confirms that a suspected cancerous tumor is benign
- end of radiation treatment - previous cancer danger is no longer present

This is not an exclusive list. General question is how "dangerously sick" does someone have to be to qualify to say *Bircat Hagomel*?

**Note** Assume for all these situations that the person is / was ill, which is why s/he's seeing the doctor. I.e. these procedures, such as colonoscopy, is not for "routine" checkup.

Comment: Say Baruch hatov vihameitiv?

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky Perhaps, you should say that **also**. Bircat Hagomel has the concept (and words) *tov* within it. I wonder if that would make it redundant?

Comment: Except that gomel is about salvation from danger and hametiv is about positive events...

Comment: So, perhaps Gomel should be said only when you have "healed" from an illness? In the above list, then, it seems that only the radiation treatment would qualify.

Comment: That would be consistent with the other incidences in which one says Gomel. I have no surviving sources referencing cancer Re: Gomel, though...

Answer (score 3):

Birchas hagomel is only said if one has an illness and has recovered from it. If one never had an illness in the first place only a suspected one there is no reason to say birchas hagomel.

Comment: guest, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for contributing answers! This answer would be a great deal more valuable if you could [edit] in sources for your assertions of Jewish law.

Comment: Here, too, you should source your answer. In all the above cases, you can assume that the person was "ill", (I'll edit that into the question), otherwise he wouldn't see the doctor. Certainly, the instances such as radiation indicate a previous illness. The question is how serious the illness must be.

Comment: Well if he was ill then he has to say the birchas hagomel. Exactly what 'grade' of illness requires this is a question for a rov.

Comment: @guest, the precise application of the rules to anyone's specific situation is a question they need to address to their rabbi. However, it's likely that there are general guidelines on the books that rabbis would work from.

Comment: When I was young I had my tonsils taken out. The rabbi didnt think I needed to make Hagomel. Whereas appendix removal is definitely a case for Hagomel.

Comment: There is no reason not to say Hagomel _without_ shem and malchut though in any appropriate situation.

Comment: I'm not sure why this gets upvotes without a source to backup the claim.